# How to bind a variant apply_visitor?

Tags: c++, boost, bind, variant

I've got this (C++03) code, but somehow, `bind` refuses to work. Any ideas why?

```
typedef boost::variant<int, string> Container;
std::vector<Container> v; 
...
class IsBad: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    typedef bool result_type;
    result_type operator()(int& t) const    { return  i % 2;     }
    result_type operator()(string& s) const { return s == "foo"; }
};
IsBad isBad;
std::vector<Container>::iterator it2 = 
         std::find_if(it, itEnd, bind(apply_visitor(isBad, _1)));
// bool is not a class, struct or union type
```

Comment: also, note that instead of nesting `typedef bool result_type;` you can put the return type in base class declaration, like `class IsBad : public boost::static_visitor<bool>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `bind`, `apply_visitor(isBad)` already returns you a functor.